# Error Loading Messages using Wialon Remote API

Tags: php

We have several GPS installed in different units and I am trying to retrieve the messages using the Wialon's Remote API but i am getting this error, can someone please help me? Thanks a lot!:

{"error":4, "reason":"VALIDATE_PARAMS_ERROR: {itemId: long, timeFrom: uint, timeTo: uint, flags: uint, flagsMask: uint, loadCount: uint}"}

Below is my script:

```
<?php
    include('wialon.php');
    $wialon_api = new Wialon();

    $token = '{token here}';
    $result = $wialon_api->login($token);
    $json = json_decode($result, true);
    if(!isset($json['error'])){
         echo $wialon_api->messages_load_interval('{"itemId":24611387,"lastTime":1073741831,"lastCount":1,"flags":0,"flagMask":0,"loadCount":1}');
        $wialon_api->logout();
    } else {
        echo WialonError::error($json['error']);
    }
?>
```

Here is the Wialon Class which i downloaded from their site:

```
<?php
    /* Classes for working with Wialon RemoteApi using PHP
    *
    * License:
    * The MIT License (MIT)
    *
    * Copyright:
    * 2002-2015 Gurtam, http://gurtam.com
    */
    
    /** Wialon RemoteApi wrapper Class
    */
    class Wialon{
        /// PROPERTIES
        private $sid = null;
        private $base_api_url = '';
        private $default_params = array();
        
        /// METHODS
        /** constructor */
        function __construct($scheme = 'https', $host = 'hst-api.wialon.com', $port = '', $sid = '', $extra_params = array()) {
            $this->sid = '';
            $this->default_params = array_replace(array(), (array)$extra_params);
            $this->base_api_url = sprintf('%s://%s%s/wialon/ajax.html?', $scheme, $host, mb_strlen($port)>0?':'.$port:'');
        }
        /** sid setter */
        function set_sid($sid){
            $this->sid = $sid;
        }
        /** sid getter */
        function get_sid(){
            return $this->sid;
        }
        /** update extra parameters */
        public function update_extra_params($extra_params){
            $this->default_params = array_replace($this->default_params, $extra_params);
        }
        /** RemoteAPI request performer
        * action - RemoteAPI command name
        * args - JSON string with request parameters
        */
        public function call($action, $args){

            $url = $this->base_api_url;

            if (stripos($action, 'unit_group') === 0) {
                $svc = $action;
                $svc[mb_strlen('unit_group')] = '/';
            } else {
                $svc = preg_replace('\'_\'', '/', $action, 1);
            }

            $params = array(
                'svc'=> $svc,
                'params'=> $args,
                'sid'=> $this->sid
            );
            $all_params = array_replace($this->default_params , $params);
            $str = '';
            foreach ($all_params as $k => $v) {
                if(mb_strlen($str)>0)
                    $str .= '&';
                $str .= $k.'='.urlencode(is_object($v) || is_array($v)  ? json_encode($v) : $v);
            }
            /* cUrl magic */
            $ch = curl_init();
            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $str
            );
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

            
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            
            if($result === FALSE)
                $result = '{"error":-1,"message":'.curl_error($ch).'}';
            
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result;
        }
        /** Login
        * user - wialon username
        * password - password
        * return - server response
        */
        public function login($token) {
            $data = array(
                'token' => urlencode($token),
            );

            $result = $this->token_login(json_encode($data));

            $json_result = json_decode($result, true);
            if(isset($json_result['eid'])) {
                $this->sid = $json_result['eid'];
            }

            return $result;
        }
        
        /** Logout
        * return - server responce
        */
        public function logout() {
            $result = $this->core_logout();
            $json_result = json_decode($result, true);
            if($json_result && $json_result['error']==0)
                $this->sid = '';
            return $result;
        }
        
        /** Unknonwn methods hadler */
        public function __call($name, $args) {
            return $this->call($name, count($args) === 0 ? '{}' : $args[0]);
        }
    }
    
    /** Wialon errorCode to textMessage converter
    */
    class WialonError{
        /// PROPERTIES
        /** list of error messages with codes */
        public static $errors = array(
            1 => 'Invalid session',
            2 => 'Invalid service',
            3 => 'Invalid result',
            4 => 'Invalid input',
            5 => 'Error performing request',
            6 => 'Unknow error',
            7 => 'Access denied',
            8 => 'Invalid user name or password',
            9 => 'Authorization server is unavailable, please try again later',
            1001 => 'No message for selected interval',
            1002 => 'Item with such unique property already exists',
            1003 => 'Only one request of given time is allowed at the moment'
        );
        
        /// METHODS
        /** error message generator */
        public static function error($code = '', $text = ''){
            $code = intval($code);
            if ( isset(self::$errors[$code]) )
                $text = self::$errors[$code].' '.$text;
            $message = sprintf('%d: %s', $code, $text);
            return sprintf('WialonError( %s )', $message);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `VALIDATE_PARAMS_ERROR` this should flag it. see their documentation on how to properly pass the data to their API

Comment: Thanks zimorok, but the documentation lacks the information i need in solving the problem